How to calculate or specify these terms Throughput, Data rate, Bandwidth?
The term "throughput" clearly refers to the actual data received in a system. For instance, with a bandwidth of 5MHz and a channel capacity (data rate) of 10Mbps, if the received data is only 6Mbps due to any reason, then the throughput is 6Mbps.
Now I have the question of how to calculate these terms in the first place?
I have specified my Bandwidth as 25e3
Now to calculate the Data rate I can use the Shannon-Hartly Formula
C = Blog2(1+SNR)
But how can I calculate the throughput from this?

Throughput is measured, not calculated. It's the practical outcome of the theoretical potential.

Throughput is measured, not calculated. It's the practical outcome of the theoretical potential. Throughput can be measured on various levels, e.g. the involved OSI layers.
Data rate has no rigid definition. Most commonly, each technology has an agreed definition for it. For Ethernet, the data rate (or nominal rate) is at the top of the physical layer. The actual transmission channel usually runs at a higher rate (nominal rate + physical-layer encoding overhead).
Bandwidth has two distinct definitions. In the network context, it usually refers to the potential, maximum throughput (also in various layers). In the physical context, the 'analog' bandwidth is the difference between the lower and the upper frequency of a channel - its width.
The Shannon-Hartley theorem tells you how the analog bandwidth limits the 'network' bandwidth in the physical layer.

how can I measure the throughput for the analysis purposes?

You can either time your application/workload or use several tools out there, but we cannot recommend products here, see the [help/on-topic].

Sorry, but I guess I'm not able to ask my question perfectly...
To analyze the performance of different modulation schemes, Is there a way to measure their throughput based on already specified Bandwidth, and channel conditions?

Yes, there is...

I need to analyze it if there is please specify some help on it Thanks
